# Why is my web grid only binding my data on my Index action function? C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

Through experimentation, I've found that the same block of code I execute in my Index (default) ActionResult function will bind data to my web grid, but if I swap this code and have it attempt to return to my view through a custom action function I wrote, the grid does not show on my rendered view.

I would like my default Index() ActionResult to return just the webpage without any special rendering.  I would like my GetPatientOneSearch() ActionResult to return the patientList I am attempting to bind and to show my web grid.

As mentioned, if I cut and paste the code in my GetPatientOneSearch and put it in my Index(), I will get search results.  I have no idea why this is happening, but it's probably something about MVC I don't understand.

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "myNameSpace";
}
@Scripts.Render(myNameSpace.Web.App.BundleConfig.GetVirtualPathForScript(myNameSpace.Web.App.BundleConfig.Scripts.PatientMerge))
@using System.Web.Helpers;

<div id="">
    <h2>
        Patient Merge
    </h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="searchOneWrp">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Patient One Search</strong></legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePone" />
                Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePone" />
                D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPOne" />
                <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPOneSearch" name="btnPOneSearch" onclick="patientOneSearch()"
                        title="Search">
                    Search
                </button>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="grdPatientOneSearch">
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.Message != "Index")
                    {
                        var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 15, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grdPatientOneSearch");
                        //grid.Bind(rowCount: 1, source: Model, autoSortAndPage: false);

                        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

                        grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",
                        headerStyle: "header",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                        selectedRowStyle: "select",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("pat_id", "Id"),
                        grid.Column("fname", "First Name"),
                        grid.Column("lname", "Last Name"),
                        grid.Column("birth_date", "dob")
                        ));
                    }

                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="searchTwoWrp">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Patient Two Search</strong></legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePTwo" />
                Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePTwo" />
                D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPTwo" />
                <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPTwoSearch" name="btnPTwoSearch"
                        title="Search">
                    Search
                </button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
using myNameSpace.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myNameSpace.Web.App.Controllers.Patient
{
    public class PatientMergeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /PatientMerge/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Index";
            //List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>();
            return View();
        }

        #region Search Function
        public ActionResult GetPatientOneSearch(string fname, string lname, string dob)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "";
            try
            {
                var target = new PatientRepository();
                var result = target.GetPatient(fname, lname, dob, "", "", "");
                List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>();

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge patient = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
                    patient.pat_id = result[i].PatientId;
                    patient.fname = result[i].FirstName;
                    patient.lname = result[i].LastName;
                    patient.birth_date = result[i].DateOfBirth.ToString();

                    patientList.Add(patient);
                }
                return View("~/Views/PatientMerge", patientList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
                //return Json(new { error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return View();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace myNameSpace.Repository.Model
{
    public class PatientMerge
    {
        public int pat_id { get; set; }
        public string pag_status_cn { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string birth_date { get; set; }
        public string AgeYears { get; set; }
        public string gender_cd { get; set; }
        public string phone_no { get; set; }
        public string addr1 { get; set; }
        public string addr2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state_cd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JS to call the controller method:

```
GetAjax('PatientMerge/GetPatientOneSearch', 'json', { 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'dob': dob }, function (data) {
            /*if (!data.success) {
                customAlert("623", "Error");
            }*/
        });
```

Comment: Which view is this? Index or PatientMerge?

Comment: @howcheng View is PatientMerge.cshtml

Comment: @Smak Did you get the answer? I'm experiencing same issue

Comment: @iamCR It has been quite some time since I've visited this issue, but I believe I reposted the problem in larger detail in a separate question.  I remember the issue itself, but I do not know how I solved it.  The link below is the only history I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620038/why-cant-my-controller-find-return-my-partialview

Answer (score 0):

So your `patientOneSearch()` function does an Ajax call to the `GetPatientOneSearch` controller action, right? And that returns a view, which will be an HTML stream. It seems to me that you're really looking for JSON data instead. The easier way to do it would be to make a form POST or GET to that action instead (use GET if you want the user to be able to link directly to search results).

```
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>Patient One Search</strong></legend>
  <form method="GET" action="GetPatientOneSearch">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" />
    D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dob" />
    <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPOneSearch" name="btnPOneSearch" type="submit" title="Search">
      Search
    </button>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```