# Why can't my controller find/return my partialview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I'm having trouble returning my partial view to my controller.  I was able to successfully do this once already, but it seems I'm having trouble doing it twice.  Error is at the end of the code.  Here's my workflow:

Controller name:

```
public class PatientMergeController : Controller
```

Page load, return view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

View returned is Index.cshtml:

```
@using ThisController = myNameSpace.Web.App.Controllers.PatientMerge.PatientMergeController
@model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>
@Scripts.Render(myNameSpace.Web.App.BundleConfig.GetVirtualPathForScript(myNameSpace.Web.App.BundleConfig.Scripts.PatientMerge))
@using System.Web.Helpers;
<div id="">
    <h2>
        Patient Merge
    </h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="searchOneWrp">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Patient One Search</strong></legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePone" />
                Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePone" />
                D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPone" />
                <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPOneSearch" name="btnPOneSearch" type="submit" onclick="SearchOne()"
                        title="Search">
                    Search
                </button>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="grdPatientOneSearch">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("PatientOneSearch", Model);}
            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientOneOrderWrp">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("PatientOneOrderDetails", Model);}
            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientOneRxWrp">

            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientOneNotesWrp">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="searchTwoWrp">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><strong>Patient Two Search</strong></legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" id="fnamePtwo" />
                Last Name: <input type="text" id="lnamePtwo" />
                D.O.B.: <input type="text" id="dobPtwo" />
                <button class="patient_look_up_button" id="btnPTwoSearch" name="btnPTwoSearch" type="submit" onclick="SearchTwo()"
                        title="Search">
                    Search
                </button>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="grdPatientTwoSearch">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("PatientTwoSearch", Model);}
            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientTwoOrderWrp">

            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientTwoRxWrp">

            </div>
            <div id="grdPatientTwoNotesWrp">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This loads some search textboxes.  When a user performs a search, they click a search button.  The search button executes this JS:

```
function SearchOne() {
    var fname = $("#fnamePone").val();
    var lname = $("#lnamePone").val();
    var dob = $("#dobPone").val();
    var url = "/PatientMerge/PatientSearch";

    //post to server, expect partial view to be returned as html, update page
    $.post(url, { 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'dob': dob, pat_number: 1 })
        .done(function (response) {
            $("#grdPatientOneSearch").html(response);
        });
}
```

The controller method PatientSearch is called:

```
public PartialViewResult PatientSearch(string fname, string lname, string dob, int pat_number)
{
    try
    {
        var target = new PatientRepository();
        var result = target.GetPatient(fname, lname, dob, "", "", "");
        List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge patient = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
            patient.pat_id = result[i].PatientId;
            patient.fname = result[i].FirstName;
            patient.lname = result[i].LastName;
            patient.phone_no = result[i].Phone;
            patient.birth_date = result[i].DateOfBirth;
            patient.AgeYears = result[i].Age;
            patient.gender_cd = result[i].Gender;
            patient.addr1 = result[i].Address1;
            patient.addr2 = result[i].Address2;
            patient.city = result[i].City;
            patient.state_cd = result[i].State;
            patientList.Add(patient);
        }
        if (pat_number == 1)
        {
            //perform patient one search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientOneSearch", patientList);
        }
        else
        {
            //perform patient two search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientTwoSearch", patientList);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge patient = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
        List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>();
        patient.fname = "Error";
        patientList.Add(patient);
        Logger.Log.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
        //return Json(new { error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (pat_number == 1)
        {
            //perform patient one search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientOneSearch", null);
        }
        else
        {
            //perform patient two search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientTwoSearch", null);
        }
    }
}
```

This controller returns the partial view PatientOneSearch.cshtml

```
@using ThisController = myNameSpace.Web.App.Controllers.PatientMerge.PatientMergeController
@model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>

@{
    myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge pat = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 20, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grdContent");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
    <div id="grdContent">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid PatientOneGrid",
                        headerStyle: "table-header",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt POneSearch",
                        selectedRowStyle: "select POneSearch",
                        rowStyle: "POneSearch",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("pat_id", "Patient ID"),
                         grid.Column("pat_status_cn", "Status"),
                        grid.Column("fname", "First Name"),
                        grid.Column("lname", "Last Name"),
                        grid.Column("birth_date", "DOB"),
                         grid.Column("AgeYears", "Age"),
                          grid.Column("gender_cd", "Gender"),
                        grid.Column("phone_no", "Phone"),
                        grid.Column("addr1", "Address 1"),
                        grid.Column("addr2", "Address 2"),
                        grid.Column("city", "City"),
                        grid.Column("state_cd", "State")
                        )
                        )
    </div>
}
else
{
    <label>No records found.</label>
}
```

The view above populates a web grid.  The below JS is waiting for row clicks.

```
<script>
    $('.POneSearch').on('click', function () {
        SearchOneGetDetails(this);
    });
</script>
```

Row clicked, execute this function:

```
function SearchOneGetDetails(obj) {
    var url = '/PatientMerge/OrderSearch';
    var patid = $(obj).find('td:first').text();

    $.post(url, { 'pat_id': patid , 'pat_number': 1 })
        .done(function (response) {
            $("#grdPatientOneOrderWrp").html(response);
        });
}
```

The controller method OrderSearch is called:

```
public PartialViewResult OrderSearch(int pat_id, int pat_number)
{
    try
    {
        var target = new PatientRepository();
        var result = target.GetPatientOrders(pat_id, "36500");
        List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder> patientList = new List<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder>();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
        {
            myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder patient = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder();
            patient.DrugName = result[i].DrugName;
            patient.InvoiceNBR = result[i].InvoiceNumber;
            patient.LineStatus = result[i].LineStatusDescr;
            patient.OrderDate = result[i].OrderDate.ToString();
            patient.OrderNum = result[i].ParentOrderNo.ToString();
            patient.PrimInsur = result[i].PrimaryInsurerName;
            patient.SeconInsur = result[i].SecondaryInsurerName;
            patient.ShipDate = result[i].ShipDate.ToString();
            patient.StorePlusID = result[i].StoreId.ToString();
            patient.TrackCode = result[i].TrackingCode;
            patientList.Add(patient);
        }
        if (pat_number == 1)
        {
            //perform patient one search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientOneOrderDetails", patientList);
        }
        else
        {
            //perform patient two search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientTwoOrderDetails", patientList);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log.Error(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.InnerException);
        if (pat_number == 1)
        {
            //perform patient one search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientOneOrderDetails", null);
        }
        else
        {
            //perform patient two search query and pone view return
            return PartialView("PatientTwoOrderDetails", null);
        }
    }
}
```

**HERE IS WHERE THE ISSUE OCCURS.**  I expect the partial view "PatientOneOrderDetails" to be returned.  My code runs and enters the if statement if(pat_number == 1) and gets to the line where the partial return is executed, but never enters into that partial file.  I do not think MVC can find my partial, but I cannot understand why.

My View structure is:

Views/PatientMerge/...

- Index.cshtml
- PatientOneSearch.cshtml
- PatientOneOrderDetails.cshtml

And here is the code for the expected view return:

```
@using ThisController = myNameSpace.Web.App.Controllers.PatientMerge.PatientMergeController
@model IEnumerable<myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge>

@{
    myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge pat = new myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge();
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 20, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grdOrderContentOne");
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
    <div id="grdOrderContentOne">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",
                        headerStyle: "table-header",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                        selectedRowStyle: "select",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column("add_date", "Order Date"),
                         grid.Column("order_id", "Order #"),
                        grid.Column("StorePlusID", "Order Store"),
                        grid.Column("LineStatus", "Line Status"),
                        grid.Column("invoice_nbr", "Script"),
                        grid.Column("drug_name", "Drug Name"),
                        grid.Column("PrimaryInsurance", "Primary Insurance"),
                        grid.Column("SecondaryInsurance", "Secondary Insurance"),
                        grid.Column("ship_date", "Ship Date"),
                        grid.Column("tracking_code", "UPS Tracking #")
                        )
                        )
    </div>
}
else
{
    <label>No records found.</label>
}
```

Comment: If you use your browsers dev tools on the network tab and watch for the response, What is being returned?

Comment: @James Internal Server Error 500 at http://localhost:57787/PatientMerge/OrderSearch, method: POST

Comment: Breakpoint the line with return, then f11 to step into the view. Might be a model or razor error. Stepping through will show you

Comment: You may have an issue in your view, which will not throw on compile time unless you specify it to do so.  Not sure the correct way to enable it but if you right click your project -> publish -> settings -> file publish options -> check precompile during publishing.   Now when you set your build to 'Release' and compile it it will fail if there are any Razor exceptions.

Comment: The model definition is wrong you expect a myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge in the partial and you are sending a myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder

Comment: @RQuijano Can you add this comment as an answer?  This was my mistake.  Thank you so much for helping!  It seriously saved me a world of pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model definition is wrong you expect a myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMerge in the partial and you are sending a myNameSpace.Repository.Model.PatientMergeOrder